# Battery life becames shorter after upgrading

Tags: power-management

When I was using Xubuntu 12.04 laptop could live 2-3 hours. Now, after installing 13.04 battery life becomes shorter and shorter.

xfce4-power-manager shows that battery is fully loaded, but after unplugging supplier, notebook works few minutes and goes down.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the blame is not on Ubuntu. If your notebook goes down your battery health has dropped, which is pretty normal.

Measure the time your computer run in BIOS. Should not be so different with an idle Session of Ubuntu.

Also, check [powertop](https://01.org/powertop/).